# Shogun fails to compile. Are these Shogun bugs?

Tags: c++, c, linux, compilation

I am trying to compile [Shogun](https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun) on Fedora 23 64bit, but it fails with the errors below. Version 4.0.0 have the same issue.

Can anyone tell me, if there errors are bugs in Shogun or something I have done wrong?

```
dnf -y install git gcc which gcc-c++ doxygen numpy make cmake wget tar bzip2

cd /tmp
wget http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/CMake-hdf5-1.8.16.tar.gz
tar xzf CMake-hdf5-1.8.16.tar.gz
cd CMake-hdf5-1.8.16
./build-unix.sh
cp -a HDF5-1.8.16-Linux/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.8.16/* /usr/local

cd /tmp
wget http://download.mosek.com/stable/7.1.0.41/mosektoolslinux64x86.tar.bz2
tar xjf mosektoolslinux64x86.tar.bz2
mv mosek/7 /root/mosek
export PATH=/root/mosek/tools/platform/linux64x86/bin/:$PATH  
cp mosek.lic /root/mosek
cd /root/mosek/tools/platform/linux64x86/python/2/  
python setup.py install --user

dnf -y install swig git cmake ccache gdb Pkgconfig NLopt-devel NLopt lpsolve-devel lpsolve ColPack-cli ColPack ColPack-devel arprec-devel arprec libxml2 libxml2-devel bzip2 bzip2-devel snappy-devel snappy protobuf-devel protobuf glpk glpk-devel libcurl-devel libcurl lzo lzo-devel lapack lapack-devel python-devel atlas atlas-devel qd qd-devel 

cd /
git clone https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun.git
cd /shogun/ && mkdir build && cd build
cmake -D BUNDLE_EIGEN=ON -D PythonModular=ON ..
make
```

And here is the output with the errors.

```
[  0%] Built target Eigen3
[  1%] Built target class_list
[  1%] Built target ChunksProtobuf
[  2%] Built target HeadersProtobuf
[  2%] Built target ShogunVersionProtobuf
[  3%] Generating version header
[  3%] Built target version
[ 75%] Built target libshogun
[ 75%] Built target shogun
[ 75%] copying SWIG files
[ 75%] Built target python_modular_src
[ 75%] Built target python_doxy2swig
[ 75%] Built target _python_modular
[ 75%] Built target shogun-static
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable balanced_conditional_probability_tree
../../../src/shogun/libshogun.so.17.1: undefined reference to `cblas_dtrsm'
../../../src/shogun/libshogun.so.17.1: undefined reference to `cblas_dgemm'
../../../src/shogun/libshogun.so.17.1: undefined reference to `cblas_sscal'
../../../src/shogun/libshogun.so.17.1: undefined reference to `cblas_dgemv'
../../../src/shogun/libshogun.so.17.1: undefined reference to `cblas_dasum'
../../../src/shogun/libshogun.so.17.1: undefined reference to `SZ_BufftoBuffDecompress'
../../../src/shogun/libshogun.so.17.1: undefined reference to `cblas_dscal'
../../../src/shogun/libshogun.so.17.1: undefined reference to `SZ_encoder_enabled'
../../../src/shogun/libshogun.so.17.1: undefined reference to `cblas_daxpy'
../../../src/shogun/libshogun.so.17.1: undefined reference to `shogun::CPrimalMosekSOSVM::CPrimalMosekSOSVM()'
../../../src/shogun/libshogun.so.17.1: undefined reference to `cblas_saxpy'
../../../src/shogun/libshogun.so.17.1: undefined reference to `cblas_ddot'
../../../src/shogun/libshogun.so.17.1: undefined reference to `cblas_dnrm2'
../../../src/shogun/libshogun.so.17.1: undefined reference to `shogun::CMosek::CMosek()'
../../../src/shogun/libshogun.so.17.1: undefined reference to `SZ_BufftoBuffCompress'
../../../src/shogun/libshogun.so.17.1: undefined reference to `cblas_sasum'
../../../src/shogun/libshogun.so.17.1: undefined reference to `cblas_dger'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
examples/undocumented/libshogun/CMakeFiles/balanced_conditional_probability_tree.dir/build.make:126: recipe for target 'examples/undocumented/libshogun/balanced_conditional_probability_tree' failed
make[2]: *** [examples/undocumented/libshogun/balanced_conditional_probability_tree] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:811: recipe for target 'examples/undocumented/libshogun/CMakeFiles/balanced_conditional_probability_tree.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [examples/undocumented/libshogun/CMakeFiles/balanced_conditional_probability_tree.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
[root@2d55f69e8521 build]#
```

**Update**

Here is the output from `cmake`

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.1.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.1.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found CCache: /usr/bin/ccache  
-- Found SWIG: /usr/lib64/ccache/swig (found suitable version "3.0.7", minimum required is "2.0.4") 
-- Performing Test _HAS_CXX11_FLAG
-- Performing Test _HAS_CXX11_FLAG - Success
-- Checking C++11 support for "__func__"
-- Checking C++11 support for "__func__": works
-- Checking C++11 support for "atomic"
-- Checking C++11 support for "atomic": works
-- Checking C++11 support for "auto"
-- Checking C++11 support for "auto": works
-- Checking C++11 support for "auto_ret_type"
-- Checking C++11 support for "auto_ret_type": works
-- Checking C++11 support for "class_override_final"
-- Checking C++11 support for "class_override_final": not supported
-- Checking C++11 support for "constexpr"
-- Checking C++11 support for "constexpr": works
-- Checking C++11 support for "cstdint"
-- Checking C++11 support for "cstdint": works
-- Checking C++11 support for "decltype"
-- Checking C++11 support for "decltype": works
-- Checking C++11 support for "initializer_list"
-- Checking C++11 support for "initializer_list": works
-- Checking C++11 support for "lambda"
-- Checking C++11 support for "lambda": works
-- Checking C++11 support for "long_long"
-- Checking C++11 support for "long_long": works
-- Checking C++11 support for "nullptr"
-- Checking C++11 support for "nullptr": works
-- Checking C++11 support for "regex"
-- Checking C++11 support for "regex": works
-- Checking C++11 support for "rvalue-references"
-- Checking C++11 support for "rvalue-references": works
-- Checking C++11 support for "sizeof_member"
-- Checking C++11 support for "sizeof_member": works
-- Checking C++11 support for "static_assert"
-- Checking C++11 support for "static_assert": works
-- Checking C++11 support for "variadic_templates"
-- Checking C++11 support for "variadic_templates": works
-- Looking for C++ include unordered_map
-- Looking for C++ include unordered_map - found
-- Using system's malloc
-- Looking for isfinite
-- Looking for isfinite - not found
-- Looking for isinf
-- Looking for isinf - found
-- Looking for isnan
-- Looking for isnan - found
-- Looking for signgam
-- Looking for signgam - found
-- Looking for fdopen
-- Looking for fdopen - found
-- Looking for log2
-- Looking for log2 - found
-- Looking for powl
-- Looking for powl - found
-- Looking for lgammal
-- Looking for lgammal - found
-- Looking for sqrtl
-- Looking for sqrtl - found
-- Looking for finite
-- Looking for finite - found
-- Looking for isfinite
-- Looking for isfinite - not found
-- Looking for isinf
-- Looking for isinf - found
-- Looking for isnan
-- Looking for isnan - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_STD_ISINF
-- Performing Test HAVE_STD_ISINF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_STD_ISFINITE
-- Performing Test HAVE_STD_ISFINITE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_STD_ISNAN
-- Performing Test HAVE_STD_ISNAN - Success
-- Looking for xmmintrin.h
-- Looking for xmmintrin.h - found
-- Looking for emmintrin.h
-- Looking for emmintrin.h - found
-- Looking for arc4random
-- Looking for arc4random - not found
-- Found GDB: /usr/bin/gdb  
-- Could NOT find MOSEK (missing:  MOSEK_DIR MOSEK_INCLUDE_DIR MOSEK_LIBRARY) 
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-fopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Success
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [-fopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Success
-- Found OpenMP: -fopenmp  
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.28") 
-- Looking for sgemm_
-- Looking for sgemm_ - found
-- A library with BLAS API found.
-- Looking for cheev_
-- Looking for cheev_ - found
-- A library with LAPACK API found.
-- Looking for clapack_dpotrf in /usr/lib64/liblapack.so
-- Looking for clapack_dpotrf in /usr/lib64/liblapack.so - not found
-- Could NOT find ATLAS (missing:  ATLAS_LIBRARIES) 
-- Found CBLAS: /lib64/libgslcblas.so  
-- Looking for cblas_dsyrk in /lib64/libgslcblas.so
-- Looking for cblas_dsyrk in /lib64/libgslcblas.so - found
-- Found GLPK: /lib64/libglpk.so  
-- Could NOT find CPLEX (missing:  CPLEX_LIBRARY CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find OPENCL (missing:  OPENCL_LIBRARY OPENCL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find ViennaCL (missing:  VIENNACL_INCLUDE_DIR OPENCL_INCLUDE_DIRS OPENCL_LIBRARIES) (Required is at least version "1.5.0")
-- checking for one of the modules 'libColPack>=1.0.9;ColPack>=1.0.9'
-- Found NLOPT: /usr/lib64/libnlopt_cxx.so  
-- Found LPSOLVE: /usr/lib64/liblpsolve55.so  
-- Found ColPack: /lib64/libColPack.so  
-- Found ARPREC: /lib64/libarprec.so  
-- Found Doxygen: /usr/bin/doxygen (found version "1.8.10") 
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.10") 
-- checking for one of the modules 'libjson>=0.11;json>=0.11;json-c>=0.11'
-- Found LibXml2: /usr/lib64/libxml2.so (found version "2.9.2") 
-- Found HDF5: /usr/local/lib/libhdf5.a (found version "1.8.16") 
-- Found CURL: /usr/lib64/libcurl.so (found version "7.43.0") 
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/local/lib/libz.a (found version "1.2.8") 
-- Found BZip2: /usr/lib64/libbz2.so (found version "1.0.6") 
-- Looking for BZ2_bzCompressInit in /usr/lib64/libbz2.so
-- Looking for BZ2_bzCompressInit in /usr/lib64/libbz2.so - found
-- Looking for lzma_auto_decoder in /usr/lib64/liblzma.so
-- Looking for lzma_auto_decoder in /usr/lib64/liblzma.so - found
-- Looking for lzma_easy_encoder in /usr/lib64/liblzma.so
-- Looking for lzma_easy_encoder in /usr/lib64/liblzma.so - found
-- Looking for lzma_lzma_preset in /usr/lib64/liblzma.so
-- Looking for lzma_lzma_preset in /usr/lib64/liblzma.so - found
-- Found LibLZMA: /usr/include (found version "5.2.1") 
-- Found SNAPPY: /usr/lib64/libsnappy.so  
-- Lzo Library /usr/lib64/liblzo2.so
-- Lzo Include Found in /usr/include
-- Spinlock support found
-- Found PROTOBUF: /usr/lib64/libprotobuf.so  
-- Supported backend(s) for linear algebra NOT FOUND/NOT ENABLED
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so (found version "2.7.10") 
-- Found NumPy: version "1.9.2" /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include
-- ===================================================================================================================
-- Summary of Configuration Variables
-- 
-- The following OPTIONAL packages have been found:

 * CCache
 * GDB
 * OpenMP
 * BLAS
 * LAPACK
 * CBLAS
 * GLPK
 * NLopt
 * LpSolve
 * ColPack
 * ARPREC
 * Doxygen
 * LibXml2
 * HDF5
 * CURL
 * ZLIB
 * BZip2
 * LibLZMA
 * SNAPPY
 * LZO
 * Spinlock
 * Threads
 * Protobuf

-- The following REQUIRED packages have been found:

 * SWIG (required version >= 2.0.4)
 * PythonLibs
 * PythonInterp
 * NumPy

-- The following OPTIONAL packages have not been found:

 * Mosek
 * Atlas
 * CPLEX
 * ARPACK
 * ViennaCL (required version >= 1.5.0)

-- The following REQUIRED packages have not been found:

 * OpenCL

-- ===================================================================================================================
-- Enabled Integration
--   OpenCV Integration is OFF   - enable with -DOpenCV=ON
-- ===================================================================================================================
-- Enabled Interfaces
--   libshogun is ON
--   python modular is ON
--   octave modular is OFF   - enable with -DOctaveModular=ON
--   java modular is OFF     - enable with -DJavaModular=ON
--   perl modular is OFF     - enable with -DPerlModular=ON
--   ruby modular is OFF     - enable with -DRubyModular=ON
--   csharp modular is OFF   - enable with -DCSharpModular=ON
--   R modular is OFF        - enable with -DRModular=ON
--   lua modular is OFF      - enable with -DLuaModular=ON
-- 
-- Enabled legacy interfaces
--   cmdline static is OFF   - enable with -DCmdLineStatic=ON
--   python static is OFF    - enable with -DPythonStatic=ON
--   octave static is OFF    - enable with -DOctaveStatic=ON
--   matlab static is OFF    - enable with -DMatlabStatic=ON
--   R static is OFF         - enable with -DRStatic=ON
-- ===================================================================================================================
-- To compile shogun type
--   make
-- 
-- To install shogun to /usr/local type
--   make install
-- 
-- or to install to a custom directory
--   make install DESTDIR=/my/special/path
--   (or rerun cmake with -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/my/special/path) to just change the prefix
-- ===================================================================================================================
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/shogun/build
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Fedora 23, shogun : `# dnf install shogun-devel`

Provides version **4.0.1**-0.1.git20150808.779c3ad.fc23

---

If you want a "build experience" : The Fedora 23 source package : shogun-4.0.1-0.1.git20150808.779c3ad.fc23.**src**.rpm → → includes also "gmock-1.7.0.zip".

Unpacking the source in /home/[name]/ : `$ rpm -i shogun-4.0.1-0.1.git20150808.779c3ad.fc23.src.rpm`

Building the packages : `$ cd rpm*/SPECS/ && rpmbuild -bb shogun.spec`

---

Answer (score 1):

You have to install `gsl-devel` too, it seems that you didn't.

```
dnf install gsl-devel
```

Comment: I got further =) Am I still missing something? Here is the complete output. http://pastebin.com/K2eLipL5

Comment: Perhaps you need   *Doxygen* too, try `dnf install doxygen`, it's a documentation generator.

Comment: That is already installed. In the following bug report they say `you must link szip -lsz`. Do you know how that is done? https://github.com/PacificBiosciences/blasr/issues/4